# How to get specific ajax result in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am not really into jquery that's why I am getting hard to get the result. I want to get the specific result of the ajax. The result of the ajax is like this:

```
{"success":1,"result":[{"id":"7","cal_events_name":"Day Off","cal_events_image":"\/assets\/img\/3_copy_copy1.png"}]}
{"success":1,"result":[{"id":"8","cal_events_name":"Normal Day","cal_events_image":"\/assets\/img\/2_copy1.png"}]}
```

How can i get only the value of `cal_events_image` ? Take note there are multiple result. Should I use `.each` function for that? Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: why there is two success? why not one success and multiple results or multiple ids sets? yes you can use `.each` to get your task done but first fix your json, it will really help you in json manipulation and fetching

Comment: okay sir i will include my controller, model code ang ajax of why there are multiple success

Comment: Did you work on your json? as i said

Comment: @M.Hemant yes sir i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse it using json. something like this...

```
success: function(response) {
var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
   for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.result.length; i++) {
     var counter = jsonData.result[i];
     console.log(counter.cal_events_image);
   }
}
```

Then it will display the result according to it's value.

here is the working example: [js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c0h7gwoe/1/)

Comment: I am just getting a `2 undefined ` when i `console.log ` it

Comment: ah.. okay i see. it will be undefined cause it's under an array

Comment: Try `obj.result[0].cal_events_image`

Comment: @angel1108 i updated my answer. let me know if it does right

Comment: anytime my friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
let response={"success":1,"result":[{"id":"7","cal_events_name":"Day Off","cal_events_image":"\/assets\/img\/3_copy_copy1.png"}]};
//response=JSON.parse(response);  // Use this line, if the response you get is in string format
alert(response["result"][0]["cal_events_name"]);
```